# CIL ANTLR grammar?

Tags: antlr, cil

Is there any .NET CIL (AKA MSIL) ANTLR grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [this publication](http://isea.nitk.ac.in/publications/web.pdf), Microsoft provides a MSIL grammar in in the Microsoft Visual Studio installation file *asmparse.grammar*. If you do not have MSVS, the grammar is also listed in the publication (see page 79).

If I'm not mistaken, that grammar could pretty much just be copied and pasted in a ANTLR grammar file (ie. it's a *[LL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) grammar*, not an *[LR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser)* one). If you're not familiar with the difference between the two, have a look at [this ANTLR article](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar).

Answer (score 2):

From [Antlr grammar list](http://antlr.org/grammar/list) - [Common Intermediate Language Parser](http://pascallacroix.free.fr/CIL/CILParser1_0.zip) by Pascal Lacroix.